# My perfect Retina image code is not working. Hi rez image loading at full size

Tags: android, css, ipad, retina-display

Here's the CSS for displaying my Retina optimized logo that I learned from this turtorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-right-way-to-retinafy-your-websites/

But! When I test on my iPad and Samsung Galaxy Note II (safari, Firefox, Dolphin apps) the retina image is showing up at its full size, which is 1200px x 500px.

So it is grabbing the right image, just not resizing it.

I have scoured the web for clues, but cannot find any. About to give up on serving retina images for now. Any ideas? Big thanks!

```
<div class="logo-splash"></div>

/* CSS for devices with normal screens */
.logo-splash {
height: 250px;
background-size: 600px 250px;
background: url(images/iaay_splash_logo.png) no-repeat center center;
}

@media only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
.logo-splash {
background-size: 600px 250px;
height: 250px;
background: url(images/iaay_splash_logo@2x.png) no-repeat center center;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've found the best way to do a retina logo imgs is simply to use a double size image.

for example if you want your logo image to be 250px x 650px

get get a version of the logo at 500px x 1300px (double) and replace your regular logo (in your case "iaay_splash_logo.png") and instead of using it as a background img use this very basic HTML

```
<div class="logo-splash">
   <img height="250px" width="600px" src="images/iaay_splash_logo.png"/>
</div>
```

Now when you access the site on a retina display it simply pulls the same image but it has double the pixels but remains the correct size as you have told it in the img tag with height="250px" width="600px".